# Ansible - synchronise files to remote hosts from local

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, synchronization

I have the following inventory:

```yaml
mta:
  hosts:
    10.1.0.3:
    10.1.0.2:
  vars:
    ansible_user: root
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/play
```

and the following task

```yaml
- name: Synchronization using rsync protocol on delegate host (push)
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
    src: "/home/play/tmp/"
    dest: "ssh://{{ mta_servers }}/tmp"
  loop: "{{ groups['mta'] }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: mta_servers
  run_once: true
  register: sync_files
```

When I run it

```
TASK [local : Synchronization using rsync protocol on delegate host ( push )] **********************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [10.1.0.4] (item=10.1.0.3) => {"ansible_loop_var": "mta_servers", "changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -i /home/play/.ssh/pwned -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /home/play/tmp/ root@10.1.0.4:ssh://10.1.0.3/tmp", "msg": "Warning: Permanently added '10.1.0.4' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.\r\nrsync: [Receiver] mkdir \"/root/ssh://10.1.0.3/tmp\" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(783) [Receiver=3.2.3]\n", "mta_servers": "10.1.0.3", "rc": 11}
failed: [10.1.0.4] (item=10.1.0.2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "mta_servers", "changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -i /home/play/.ssh/pwned -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /home/play/tmp/ root@10.1.0.4:ssh://10.1.0.2/tmp", "msg": "Warning: Permanently added '10.1.0.4' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.\r\nrsync: [Receiver] mkdir \"/root/ssh://10.1.0.2/tmp\" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(783) [Receiver=3.2.3]\n", "mta_servers": "10.1.0.2", "rc": 11}
```

Facts to be known

I'm running the playbook on 10.1.0.4 as the user `play`, then I'm connecting to local as root with a pubkey.

The reason I'm doing this, is because eventually I want to generate letsencrypt certificates on localhost and then sync them to the above servers.

What bugs me is that, whatever directory I choose as the target (`dest: "ssh://{{ mta_servers }}/tmp"`), if would fail still.

detailed output `-vvv`

```json
failed: [10.1.0.4] (item=10.1.0.2) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "mta_servers",
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -i /home/play/.ssh/pwned -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /home/play/tmp/ root@10.1.0.4:ssh://10.1.0.2/tmp",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_local_rsync_password": null,
            "_local_rsync_path": "rsync",
            "_substitute_controller": false,
            "archive": true,
            "checksum": false,
            "compress": true,
            "copy_links": false,
            "delay_updates": true,
            "delete": false,
            "dest": "root@10.1.0.4:ssh://10.1.0.2/tmp",
            "dest_port": null,
            "dirs": false,
            "existing_only": false,
            "group": null,
            "link_dest": null,
            "links": null,
            "mode": "push",
            "owner": null,
            "partial": false,
            "perms": null,
            "private_key": "/home/play/.ssh/pwned",
            "recursive": null,
            "rsync_opts": [],
            "rsync_path": null,
            "rsync_timeout": 0,
            "set_remote_user": true,
            "src": "/home/play/tmp/",
            "ssh_args": null,
            "ssh_connection_multiplexing": false,
            "times": null,
            "verify_host": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Warning: Permanently added '10.1.0.4' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.\r\nrsync: [Receiver] mkdir \"/root/ssh://10.1.0.2/tmp\" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(783) [Receiver=3.2.3]\n",
    "mta_servers": "10.1.0.2",
    "rc": 11
}
```

```bash
[play@ans ansible]$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /home/play/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/play/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/play/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.14 (main, Jan  9 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

RHEL9

Comment: `dest: "rsync://{{ mta_servers }}/tmp"`. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#examples

Comment: Why don't you target your group in a play rather than looping on it?

Comment: i've also tried with rsync, couple of days ago - is the same result - `mkdir \"/root/rsync:/10.1.0.3/tmp\" failed: No such file or directory` - notice the single `/` so it would use port `22` instead of the default `873` - I really tried everything I could find on the web. thanks for the downvote ...

Comment: You need two slashes.

Comment: I did mentioned the reason I'm using single `/`

Comment: `I really tried everything I could find on the web` => then in that case please add an evidence of those tries in your question and links to the documentation you have read. Ansible will not interpret the path as rsync with a single slash. There are other parameters in the documentation I linked above to change the ssh port for the rsync target. But anyway you don't need all this, see my answer.

Comment: Last, yes I take full responsibility for the downvote: your code blocks where not formatted correctly, the problem is caused by a typo, you don't give evidence of what you have already tried (and people migth propose solutions already tested)... but notice I still (tried to) help. A downvote is a simple marker someone thinks your question does not meet the expected standard, not a judgement on your own person. Complaining about downvotes does not help. Making your question better usually does. And since I'm not omniscient, someone can still upvote it (and I can change my vote to if you [edit])

Comment: thanks for your honesty. if I do use double `/` ansible will try and use the default port `873` - because I get connection refused ( I didn't opened that port ) and if I don't it uses `22` - I complained about the downvote because I didn't knew the reason, now I do, sort of. iMO, I formatted correctly if you mean readability - if you mean content, I tried to keep it short, hence only providing the relevant code and yes I should've mentioned all the solutions I have tried. I really appreciate the effort and time to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making this overly complicated and your `dest` string is not correct anyway (either the one in your question or in your comment).

All you need is to target your group in a play and use that natural loop to rsync to each target host.

```yaml
- name: sync my files
  hosts: mta

  tasks:
    - name: push files to target with rsync
      ansible.posix.synchronize:
        src: "/home/play/tmp/"
        dest: "/tmp/"
      register: sync_files
```

Comment: I do tend to over think or over complicate things. I had the impression that if I execute the play on local I need to use rsync for the remote servers ... but ansible takes care of that ... smart :)

Answer (score 2):

For example, synchronize localhost *`/tmp/foo/`* to *`/tmp/bar/`* on two remote servers *test_12* and *test_13*. Given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo
├── file1
└── file2

0 directories, 2 files
```

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_12,test_13

  tasks:

    - ansible.posix.synchronize:
        src: /tmp/foo/
        dest: /tmp/bar/
      register: sync_files

    - debug:
        var: sync_files.stdout_lines
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [test_12,test_13] ***********************************************************************

TASK [ansible.posix.synchronize] *************************************************************
changed: [test_12]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_12] => 
  sync_files.stdout_lines:
  - .d..t...... ./
  - <f+++++++++ file1
  - <f+++++++++ file2
ok: [test_13] => 
  sync_files.stdout_lines:
  - .d..t...... ./
  - <f+++++++++ file1
  - <f+++++++++ file2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_12: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Take a look at the files on the remote hosts

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_12 ls -1 /tmp/bar/
file1
file2
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 ls -1 /tmp/bar/
file1
file2
```

---

Notes:

- Your title says *"Synchronise files to remote hosts from local"* but the name of the task says *"Synchronization using rsync protocol on delegate host (push)"*. Push using the rsync protocol requires running the rsync daemon on the destination. See the [*Notes*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#notes).
- Push is the default [*mode*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#parameter-mode)
- You don't have to specify *ssh* protocol in the destination URL. See the *cmd* attribute of the registered variable, e.g.

> cmd: /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --dry-run --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u root rsync' --out-format='<>%i %n%L' /tmp/foo/ admin@test_12:/tmp/bar/

- You don't have to delegate to localhost. The controller is the default source.
- Do not iterate the hosts. It's both simpler and faster to let them run in parallel.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and or the explanation.

the `name` was literally copy and paste from ... somewhere - I didn't think it would matter for the question.

 as previously said, I want to synchronise the letsencrypt certs from local to remote - but `/etc/letencrypt/accounts` can only be read by `root` - even if I add `become: yes` to the task, I still get permission denied ... can you help ?

Comment: There are two parts: 1) reading on the controller and 2) writing to the remote host (might be localhost making the controller and remote host the same host). `become` applies to the second part only. This is how Ansible works. Pack a code and data in the first part. Send the package to the remote host. Unpack it on the remote host and execute the code. As a result, you must be root to read root files on the controller by any module in its first part. It's up to you how you solve this security problem.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I used compress & uncompress modules.